# How to Get Next 3 month Date Android

Tags: android, date, calendar

i use this code to get today's date and display it

```
m_today = Calendar.getInstance();
```

now how can i get the next 3 month date?
something like this:

NOV 21.2012 to FEB 21,2013

i can display the first part but how to display second part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
m_today.add(Calendar.MONTH, 3);
```

Answer (score 7):

This should work,

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); //Get the Calendar instance
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH,3);//Three months from now
cal.getTime();// Get the Date object
```